# Why cant i simply create a Business Central container in Azure?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-container-instances, dynamics-business-central

Im trying to create a Business Central container in Azure and am using the following in powershell.

```
  $imageName = “mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763”
  $resourceGroup = “d365rg”
  $location = “EastUS”
  $containerName = “d365bcdemo02”
  $dnsName = “d365bcdemo02.eastus.azurecontainer.io”
  $artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -type sandbox -country us -select Latest

  az container create -g $resourceGroup -n $containerName --image $imageName --os-type Windows --cpu 2 
  --memory 16 --ip-address public -e artifactUrl=$artifactUrl ACCEPT_EULA=Y USESSL=N ClickOnce=Y 
  publicDnsName=$dnsName --dns-name-label $containerName --ports 80 7046 7047 7048 7049 8080
```

But am constantly getting the error:

```
  "az : The image 'mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763' in container group 'd365bcdemo02' is 
  not accessible. Please check the image and registry credential."
```

What credentials , i dont have a container registry and dont think you need one. What could be happening here ?

Comment: Can you really find the image with the tag? The image does not have the tag you want to use.

Comment: How do you mean find the image , just put in the browser url ? If i do i go to  https://github.com/microsoft/containerregistry

Comment: Where do you find the tag? Share the page.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-20H2%2Cwindows-10-20H2           look under Practical application heading ..

Comment: and i even followed the following example:     https://demiliani.com/2020/07/03/creating-a-dynamics-365-business-central-docker-container-with-artifacts-on-azure-container-instances/      and still same error .

Comment: These just are the version of the Windows OS, not the image. As I see, the image just has the tag shown in the examples [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-businesscentral).

Comment: Watch out! The same image with the same tag, not in different images.

Comment: So the imagename is ok , but why it  gives the above error ? have i set something wrong ? Im new to creating containers and any help would be good to learn .

Comment: Yeah, the image does not have the tag. Do you understand?

Comment: sorry i dont .. do i need to change this to specify sandbox ?    $imageName = “mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral:10.0.17763”

Comment: Yes, find an available tag of the image. That's it.

Comment: Do you solve the problem?

Comment: I did literally just now.. it was a version issue , the image tag was wrong .. corrected it . thanks

Comment: I will add an answer, if you don't mind, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the wrong image tag. So the solution is to use the tag available in the image.